# What are the three values in the csv graph of price history?

Tags: history, charts

I wanted to look up the price history of bitcoin on different exchanges (in order to compare them in one graph) and I found [this site](http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/csv/) with the data organized in csv type files. What do the three values correspond to?

For example in coinbase BTC/EUR the first few lines are

> 1429753354,300.000000000000,0.010000000000
>   1429766376,200.000000000000,0.010000000000
>   1429831674,220.000000000000,0.010000000000
>   1429841387,220.000000000000,0.010000000000
>   1430156722,205.270000000000,0.035300000000
>   1430156722,205.270000000000,0.064700000000
>   1430156880,205.330000000000,0.100000000000
>   1430159153,205.340000000000,0.010000000000
>   1430177802,209.470000000000,0.014260000000
>   1430192991,209.190000000000,0.022200000000
>   1430192991,209.110000000000,0.048500000000
>   1430192991,209.100000000000,0.029300000000
>   1430193080,209.530000000000,0.099000000000
>   1430220205,209.030000000000,0.100000000000
>   1430252864,204.480000000000,0.010000000000
>   1430261840,204.900000000000,0.356800000000
>   1430261840,204.870000000000,0.167600000000
>   1430261840,204.670000000000,0.156200000000
>   1430261840,204.660000000000,0.979400000000
>   1430263167,205.490000000000,0.010000000000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unix Time, Price, Amount of Value in the Order Book at Corresponding price.

So the first line in your example translates to Thursday, April 23, 2015 GMT time, there was an order for 0.01 bitcoins at the price of $300.